# Unexpectedly missing implicitly declared copy/move constructors

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, c++17, move-constructor, implicit-declaration

Consider the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct F;

template <typename R, typename... As>
struct F<R(As...)>
{
    template <typename F_, std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_invocable_r_v<R, std::decay_t<F_>, As...>>*...>
    F(F_&&) {}

    F() = default;

    template <typename... As_, std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_invocable_v<void(As&&...), As_...>>*...>
    R operator()(As_&&...)
    { return R(); }
};

struct C
{
    F<C()> f_;

    // C(C&&) = default;  // <<< 1
};

int main() {
    F<C(int)> x;
    auto y = x;
}
```

gcc 7.3.0 fails to compile it (deep within `std::is_invocable_r`):

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type
    ‘struct std::__or_<std::is_void<C>, std::is_convertible<C, C> >’
```

as does clang 5.0.1:

```
error: no type named 'type' in
    'std::__or_<std::is_void<C>, std::is_convertible<C, C> >'
```

From this I deduce that `C` is missing move and copy constructors. Indeed, if we uncomment its move constructor (1), this code compiles.

I believe the requirements for them to be implicitly declared are satisfied. Why aren't they?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think by declaring a move constructor in `F`, you implicitly delete `F`'s copy constructor, which in turn implicitly deletes `C`'s copy constructor.  I would try implementing (or `default`ing/`delete`ing) `F`'s copy constructor, copy/move assignment operators, and destructor to follow the rule of 5.

Comment: @DanielLangr Ahh, good point.

Comment: The move constructor in `F` is implicitly defined.

Comment: I think this is ill-formed NDR, but I'm not sure why...

Comment: See: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QyLQVFjohdW5XBok

Comment: At `F<C()> f_;`, `C` is an incomplete type, which corresponds with `R` template parameter within `F`, where it is used as template argument for `std::is_invocable_r_v`. Template arguments of `std::is_invocable_r_v` cannot be incomplete types. But I am not sure whether this is the cause of the reported problem. If it is, then you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielLangr this appears to be the case, yes. Would you care to make this an answer?

Comment: @yurikilochek I will, just trying to dig a bit deeper into the problem. I still cannot figure out why uncommenting the defaulted move constructor makes the code compilable. Although, if there is undefined behavior, then a compiler is free to behave anything it wants during compilation as well.

Comment: @yurikilochek Why should any implicitly-defined constructor of `C` invoke `F::F(F_&&)`? Implicitly-defined constructors of `C` should only invoke implicitly-defined constructors of `F` in this case, not this user-proveded template constructor. Moreover, the code compiles even when I comment out the whole definition of `F::F(F_&&)` constructor. And, what's "worse", also when I comment out the definition of `operator()`.

Comment: @DanielLangr `F::F(F_&&)` is not invoked, but it has to be instantiated to perform overload resolution. But that (deleted) comment was bullshit anyway because explicitly defaulted constructors do the same thing, and still cause UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that here:

```
F<C()> f_;
```

`C` is an incomplete type. Within `F`, `C` substitutes the template parameter `R`, which is then used as a template argument of `std::is_invocable_r_v`. The Standard does not allow to use incomplete types as template arguments of `std::is_invocable_r_v` and it results in undefined behavior. Undefined behavior includes, among others, arbitrary behavior of a compiler during compilation.

---

Note that I am not completely sure about my answer, mainly because neither the templated `F::F` constructor nor its templated `operator()` is instantiated.

Comment: `F::F` is instantiated though, from within the default definition of `C`'s copy/move constructors, which perform member-wise direct-initialization.

Comment: @yurikilochek Why would be instantiated the templated `F::F`? It is not invoked anywhere. Does it need to be instantiated for constructor overload resolution?